# How to check whether given xy coordinate lies inside a web map imported from arcgis online?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to know when i have imported a web map to arcgis javascript api from arcgis online then how to check whether a given xy coordinate lies inside that web map. I know there is a method in polygons as point in polygon. But I do not know how to convert imported web map to a polygon. need a help.

Comment: Do you mean the extent or the bounding box of that map?

Comment: i want to know when i visualize a my own web map to arcgis api then given coordinates are lie on the map area or lie outside the map area

Comment: same as polygon.conatains(point) method. but how it apply like webmap.contains(point)

Comment: Are you asking about if a point is within the initial extent of the web map?

Comment: if a point is in the area of the web map or not? means a point is covered by map or not?